# Как связать две переменные в классе, чтобы одна содержалась в другой?

Tags: python

начал немного учить питон и застрял как мне кажется на очень простой вещи.
Я думал, что если я поменяю значение в переменой **name**, то значение применится и к переменной **description**, но так не произошло. Экземпляры от класса я не создаю, а использую просто в качестве хранилища строковых значений, которые потом используются в коде.

Код:

```
class Data:
    name = "Tom"
    description = f'His name is {name}'
    
Data.name = "Roman"
print(Data.name) // "Roman"
print(Data.description) //"His name is Tom"
```

Comment: В вашем коде проблема в том, что `description = ...` исполнится только один раз - при инициализации класса. Поэтому там будет то, что было на этот момент.

Comment: Кто учил так оформлять комментарии в питоне?

Answer (score 2):

Обычно всё же используют экземпляры класса для для хранения данных. Для удобства посмотрите в сторону NamedTuple или Dataclasses.
Но если делать как решили вы, то можно воспользоваться декораторами

```
class Data:
  name = "Tom"

  @classmethod
  @property
  def description(cls):
    return f'His name is {cls.name}'

Data.name = "Tom"
print(Data.name) # Tom
print(Data.description) # His name is Tom
Data.name = "Roman"
print(Data.name) # Roman
print(Data.description) # His name is Roman
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ.